# Get the value of count for the duplicate string

Tags: java

I want to count the value of distinct user. This is my logfile. In  log file if remote address is same for the two request then it will count it as one request because it comes from one user. So how can I check the duplicate value of remote address in java.

```
Request Date:  Wed Dec 24 06:01:46 IST 2014
LATITUDE: 22.3007861
LONGITUDE: 73.1426661
remote address: 106.78.195.239
Remote Host: 106.78.195.239
Case1 :Response sent

Request Date:  Wed Dec 24 06:01:55 IST 2014
LATITUDE: 22.3007861
LONGITUDE: 73.1426661
remote address: 106.78.195.239
Remote Host: 106.78.195.239
Case1 :Response sent

Request Date:  Wed Dec 24 07:20:26 IST 2014
LATITUDE: 22.2828575
LONGITUDE: 73.180606
remote address: 49.14.205.199
Remote Host: 49.14.205.199
Case1 :Response sent

Request Date:  Wed Dec 24 07:20:37 IST 2014
LATITUDE: 22.2828575
LONGITUDE: 73.180606
remote address: 49.14.205.199
Remote Host: 49.14.205.199
Case1 :Response sent
```

Comment: have you tried adding them to a *Set*?

Comment: use Set and get the set.size().

Comment: whats the main problem are you unable to parse the file or count the distinct user.

Comment: The problem is that how can I parse the file and add it to the set.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `Set` class:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Just parse your log file and add the remote adresses to a Set. Since `Set` can't have duplicate values, use `mySet.Size()` when you're done.